# What is the most frequently occurring health problem of rodents caused by the usage of pesticides on the agricultural fields in the United States?

Tags: pesticide

For centuries the mankind has used pesticides to protect its crops but within the last century the pesticides have become more artificial and toxic. It is a well known fact that most of the pesticides can have fatal consequences, when one consumes them to much, as different studies have shown links between the pesticides and different diseases like cancer, ADHD and also different birth defects. People today are more aware about it and try to eat more organic food, but the pesticides are still in constant use and therefore it is still a threat to animals, who are in direct contact with the pesticides.